# Google Checkout Sandbox not working

Tags: google-checkout

I have created sanbox merchant account in google checkout but when i have submitted this form i got this error message 
    " Oops!
Bilal has sent Google a shopping cart with errors in it. We'll contact them to ask that they fix this problem. As this could be a temporary issue, you can go back in your browser to try checking out again. 
    Debugging information

```
If you are acting on behalf of the merchant, more information about this error has been made available in the Integration Console under the Tools section. You can access the details of this error directly by logging into your merchant account and then pasting the following url:
https://sandbox.google.com/checkout/sell/settings?section=IntegrationConsole&returnURL=https%3A%2F%2Fsandbox.google.com%2Fcheckout%2Fsell%2Fsettings%3Fsection%3DIntegrationConsole&serialNumber=523b617a-106c-4c87-a2cc-135e20c983eb "


The Form that i have created as follows:

     var output_data1 =   <form   id ="GC" name="GC" method="POST" action="https://sandbox.google.com/checkout/api/checkout/v2/checkoutForm/Merchant/ 922635804601464" accept-charset="utf-8">';
                                        output_data1 += "Please wait while we are redirecting to the Payment Gateway.";
                                        output_data1 += '<input type="hidden" name="item_name_1" value="'+monument_name+'">';
                                        output_data1 +='<input type="hidden" name="item_description_1" value="'+monument_color+'">';
                                        output_data1 += '<input type="hidden" name="item_quantity_1" value="1">';
                                        output_data1 += '<input type="hidden" name="item_price_1" value="'+AMOUNT+'">';
                                        output_data1 += '<input type="hidden" name="item_currency_1" value="USD">';
                                        output_data1 += '<input type="hidden" name="ship_method_name_1" value="UPS Ground">';
                                        output_data1 += '<input type="hidden" name="ship_method_price_1" value="0.0">';
                                        output_data1 += 

'<input type="hidden" name="ship_method_currency_1" value="USD">';
                                        //output_data1 += '<input type="hidden" name="tax_rate" value="0.0875">';
                                        output_data1 += '<input type="hidden" name="tax_us_state" value="CA">';

                                        output_data1 += '<input type="hidden" name="checkout-flow-support.merchant-checkout-flow-support.continue-shopping-url" value="http://www.thegranitemonumentcompany.com/p/Main">';

                                        output_data1 += '<input type="hidden" name="_charset_">';
                                        output_data1 += '</form>'
```

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell from your description where the problem is. I'm including two Checkout error troubleshooting articles, hope it helps.

Google Checkout - Cart Post Oops Error Troubleshooting:

http://code.google.com/apis/checkout/articles/Google_Checkout_Cart_Post_Troubleshooting.html

Troubleshooting Integration Console Errors:

http://code.google.com/apis/checkout/articles/Troubleshoot_Integration_Console_Errors.html